# Fixing JRE error in Java code and recompiling application

Tags: java, runtime-error, java-7, code-snippets, sfx

I tried run on Windows 7 some old utility that depends on old JRE version.

I have last `Java Runtime Environment 1.7.0_79` installed. When I attepmt to start application, I got an error:

> "Sivus requires JRE 1.4 or later to run. You can download JRE
>   from...etc"

Is there a workaround to resolve/fix this or something of that nature?
Program main executable packed in SFX ZIP archive, I extracted files, and found [Java file](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=00640799172309611792), which makes the check. There is a code:

```
  public static boolean checkJavaVersion(){
    boolean ok = false;
    String version = System.getProperty("java.version");

    if (version.indexOf("1.1") > -1) {
      ok = false;
    }
    else if (version.indexOf("1.2") > -1) {
      ok = false;
    }
    else if (version.indexOf("1.3") > -1) {
      ok = false;
    }
    else if (version.indexOf("1.4") > -1) {
      ok = true;
    }
    else if (version.indexOf("1.5") > -1) {
      ok = true;
    }

    return ok;
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean DEBUG = false;
    try {


    // check if JRE is over 1.4
    if (checkJavaVersion() == false){
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
          null,
          "SiVuS requires JRE 1.4 (or later) to run.\n"
          +"You can download the latest JRE from java.sun.com",
          "Java Run Time Environment Error",
          JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
      System.exit(1);
    }
```

How to correct this issue and recompile the application again? Will the application that relies on JRE 1.4 work with current JRE?

Comment: did tou check it with JRE 1.4 ?

Comment: I have no JRE 1.4, it's too old.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example of how I'm doing patches like this.

1. Fix code - you can add 1.6, 1.7, 1.8 to checkJavaVersion or remove this check at main method.
2. Put fixed java file in folder that matches package
3. Compile java file, for example:

   call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\javac.exe" C:\test\mypackage\MyClass.java -cp C:\test\My.jar -source 1.4 -target 1.4
4. Get compiled class file and replace old file (backup it first)

Comment: p3: this requres compiling MyClass.java? I can't just edit target myfile.java, then recreate SFX executable? The extracted SFX package have no any `.jar` files. There is myfile.java and myfile.class

Comment: My.jar - for example, if there only one java file you can skip "-cp ...". And I think its not enough to just edit java file.

Comment: So I should use only this command to recreate corresponding myfile.class: `call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\javac.exe" C:\test\mypackage\MyClass.java`?

Comment: I have only JRE installed, without JDK. Is there a separate JDK version, or its only bundled with JRE?

Comment: separate - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html

Comment: Tried to compile adjusted file on Linux, `java version "1.6.0_32"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.13.4) (6b32-1.13.4-1~deb7u1)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)`, but failed, got 3 [errors](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=bBQTEUbG).

Comment: is there voipScannerUI.java, splashScreen.java and other java files in package?

Comment: Place this files, keep directory structure and run compilation again. You can place java file or better class files.

Comment: I fixed the issue by patching the executable directly, without recompiling. All is working now.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would recommend not using an old tool whose "provenance" is doubtful.  Especially, not as a security scanner.  Surely, you can find a tool that is newer, and better supported than this one ...

If you wish to proceed (and take a risk) then one approach would be to modify that class, recompile and rebuild the JAR file, as suggested by @Rustam.

Another approach would be to create a simple wrapper class with a `main` method that called `System.setProperty` to tweak the value of the `"java.version"` property, and then called the real `main` method.